# List all ODATA.NEXTLINK without getting values

Tags: powershell, odata, invoke-restmethod

Anybody have an idea how in powershell we could list all @ODATA.NEXTLINK without crawling the values.
We have 130k users and using the paging of invoke-restmethod on https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users take a very long time.

Idea would be to get only the ODATA.NEXTLINK value and then use the batching feature of GRAPH to speed up things by executing 10 to 20 call in a same JSON batch

all my tries execute the crawl of the values so far
my expectation would be a list of @ODATA.NEXTLINK

Comment: This isn't possible afaik. But also for querying 130k users for that API shouldn't take longer than 10 minutes

Comment: Are the links in a predictable pattern - e.g. ```…?page=1```, ```…?page=2``` or ```…?offset=100```, ```…?offset=200``` etc so you could generate them? Or are they in the format ```…?continuationToken=<random guid>```